# Off Canvas submenu not showing using Ink Sapo UI Kit

Tags: html, css, ink.sapo.pt

As shown below I have a left drawer for off canvas menu with a submenu flyout right but the submenu does not show upon hover or click.  What is wrong? I am using Ink UI Kit by SAPO version 3.1.10.

```
<!-- _includes/left-drawer.html -->
  <div class="left-drawer">
    <nav class="ink-navigation">
      <ul class="menu vertical black">
        <li class="sactive"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Post archive</a>
            <ul class="submenu flyout right">
                <li><a href="#">January</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">February</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">March</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the default behavior in Ink Ui Kit.